# React doesn't append class from className

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem with React and don't know why, but React doesn't appent the attribute `class` in rendered HTML code. I import css file in body, import styles in react script, write className attribute, etc..

The result on page will be block without class – `<div>test</div>`

In `App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from '../assets/main.css';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className={styles.test}>test</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In `main.css`

```
.test {
    color: red;
}
```

Webpack config

```
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        __dirname + '/app/index.js'
    ],
    devServer: {
        hot: true
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: __dirname + '/build'
    },
    plugins: [
        HTMLWebpackPluginConfig,
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    }
};
```

Comment: Who's calling App.js? In this code, you've created App.js but no one's calling/using it

Comment: `className` should be a string, not an object; it looks like you're conflating classes and styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing your CSS stylesheet just causes Webpack to bundle it along with the rest of your JavaScript. You can't add `styles.test` as an attribute, that won't do anything. You need to specify the `className` as a string, just like you would for an HTML element.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="test" >test</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I tried write like this before and it's doesn't work. But now all is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try importing your main.css file in your entry file i.e app/index.js. You don't need to add {styles.test} in className.

```
import './assets/main.css';
```

When the webpack bundle will run it will take all your css.

You just need to give same className like :

```
        <div>
            <div className='test'>test</div>
        </div>
```

Also, make sure you have installed all loaders like file-loader, css-loader, url-loader, style-loader and included them in your webpack.config file.